# Docker custom dns resolve among containers

Tags: curl, docker, dns, docker-compose, docker-network

I have following `docker-compose.yml`

```
php:
    build: ./phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ~/works/codes:/code

web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ~/works/codes:/code
        - ./nginx/etc/conf.d/virtual.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf
        - ./nginx/var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
        - php
```

I've 2 virtual hosts setup inside web container

```
app.lan
api.lan
```

In my `php` application I do curl to `api.lan`. But it throws `Could not resolve host: api.lan`

In my docker host I've added following to `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 app.lan
127.0.0.1 api.lan
```

I can curl from docker host machine to `api.lan` without a problem. But seems `web` container doesn't resolve name from docker host machine.

If I find the `web` container's ip and put that into the php container's hosts file as follows it works.

```
172.18.0.5 api.lan
```

But how do I automate this on docker compose. Or any other best practices for this?

In addition if I cat `/etc/resolve.conf` of either container I can find following.

```
search local
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

What's this 127.0.0.11? Is it the host machine?

I'm on "Docker for mac" `v 1.12.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chris Pointed out I need to use docker's `extra_hosts` and also I needed to create a network and assign IPs to each docker container.

Following is my full `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"

networks:
    lan_0:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.19.0.0/24
                  gateway: 172.19.0.21

services:
    php:
        build: ./phpfpm
        volumes:
            - ~/works/codes:/code
        extra_hosts:
            - "api.lan:172.19.0.21"
        networks:
            lan_0:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.22

    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ~/works/codes:/code
            - ./nginx/etc/conf.d/virtual.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf
            - ./nginx/var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
        networks:
            lan_0:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.21
```

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.11 is docker's internal dns that allows containers to communicate with each other directly by name ('web' and 'php' in your case).

You can add extra entries to docker using [extra hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/extrahosts) in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: But you need manually add each host in this case, and what will you do on each docker restart when IP's change.

Comment: Dockers internal dns does this for you, you can use the name of the container to always point to it's latest IP address.

Comment: Yes, but in current case you need to access php via nginx. You can't receive response from php container directly. So you need that api1.com routes to nginx:80 port, not php. Php container has only php:9000 daemon listener, who will proceed requests from webserver only.

Answer (score 1):

> In my php application I do curl to `api.lan`

Don't do that.  Use the hostnames provided by docker `web` and `php` (the names you gave to the services in your `docker-compose.yml` are created as hostnames that can be used by other containers.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. Because I'm running multiple virtual hosts in the same `web` container.